# MongoDB aggregation find document pairs using list of pairs that cannot go together

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

If I have the following data structure

```
{
     "_id": <id_of_document>,
     "name": <name_of_person>
}
```

I am trying to find a way of matching each person randomly with another person in the collection.

I have the following constraints a list of ids that can't go together, i.e.

```
[
    [1, 2],
    [10, 6],
]
```

the following shows that 1 and 2 cannot go together and 10 and 6 cannot go together but 1 and 10  could go together and 6 and 2 could go together.

How would I show this in a mongoDB aggregation?

Comment: $lookup then pipeline with $nin sounds workable.

Comment: I have that explained poorly, I don't have the constraints in a separate collection I just have them in a list in memory. I don't think lookup is what I need.

Comment: You could construct a giant $expr then.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example? I am struggling to understand how to use $expr

Comment: If you are  asking for examples, update the question with runnable code that inserts your data and contains the query you managed to construct so far.